# How do I detect if a drag operation was cancelled using NSDraggingInfo or similar?

Tags: objective-c, macos, drag-and-drop, nsimageview, nsdragginginfo

I've created a subclass of NSImageView and implemented the informal protocol for dragging images between other instances of the same class. I am keeping a reference to the image of the view prior to the dragging operation and am able to set it back to said image given certain criteria.

However, I can't seem to detect if the dragging operation was cancelled. I know that the draggingEnded method is called but it is also called when a drag was successful. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered a similar requirement. The fact that you can examine the `operation` argument passed to the NSDraggingSource protocol method `draggedImage:endedAt:operation:` to detect drag cancellation is not very well documented.

In the `draggedImage:endedAt:operation:` method just add the following check:

```
if (operation == NSDragOperationNone)
    return;

// Otherwise perform any drag completion tasks.
```